# Ubuntu Upgrade not finishing

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, 14.10, cron

I am upgrading ubuntu 14.10 to 16 LTS using a DVD and well it has been at the saving installed packages phase for more than 2 hours.What should I do?

Here is a screenshot [image]